# How to uncheck programmatically a radiobutton after it was clicked manually?

Tags: javascript

There are radiobuttons on a form :

```
...
for ( $i = $data["figure"]["cnt"] / 2; $i < $data["figure"]["cnt"]; $i++) {
    $tabFields[4]['html'] .= '
        <td align="center">     
            <input type="radio" id="fig_"'.$i.' name="fig_code" value="' . $data["figure"][$i]["fig_code"] . '" onchange="verifier_usage_figure('. $data["figure"][$i]["fig_code"] .')" />
        </td>';
...
```

In the `verifier_usage_figure` function I want to uncheck the clicked radio when a certain condition is met. How to code that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [JS Radio checked property](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_radio_checked.asp)

```
document.getElementById("elementId").checked = false;
```

Comment: Or, in the jQuery way: `$('#elementId').removeAttr('checked');`

Answer (score 0):

write javascript function which include the stmnt
   
    `document.getElementById("elementId").checked = false;` this function must include the invokation of this function in the verifier_usage_figure() function 
 in this case "fig_"'.$i must be used in the place of elementid and make sure the above code is written in the verifier_usage_figure()

Comment: ist thing you have to improve your coding style becoz you look the code in your question can be simply written as follows..

Comment: $tabFields[4]['html'] .= "
        <td align='center'>     
            <input type='radio' id='fig_$i' name='fig_code' value=' $data[figure][$i][fig_code] 'onchange='verifier_usage_figure( $data[figure][$i][fig_code])/></td>";